# Rails 2, define route with a param containing slashes and dots

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I would like to define URLs like these ones:

```
/pages/VAR.1
/pages/VAR/1
```

So I try different configs (but none of them works):

```
map.page 'pages/:id', :controller => 'pages', :action => 'custom', :constraints => { :id => /[^\/]+/ }
map.page 'pages/:id', :controller => 'pages', :action => 'custom', :constraints => { :id => /(.*)+/ }
```

and the application redirects to 404 page. How should I do?
I'm working with ruby 1.8.7 and rais 2.3.18

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Oh... my fault! I'm used with rails3, but rails2 uses "requirements" instead of "constraints".